# A path between two elements of a group

Tags: group-theory

Though this is my first post, as far as I understand, questions on MSE should explain how the OP came across the problem. However, this problem was not something I came across, but rather something I have been mulling over for some time. As I have seen more problems, there have been many times where I have thought that an answer to this question, or some very similar question, would be helpful.

Here is the question:

Given some elements $a, b \in G$, where $G$ is an infinite group, and some other elements $c, d \in G$ where $H = \langle c, d\rangle$ ($H$ is a free group), is there any easy-ish way to tell whether $ab \in H$?

Comment: Probably not. This can get very complicated.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without more information on how the group is defined. There are likely to be situations  in which the question is undecidable. Also, why involve $b$ at all? You could equivalently just ask how to test whether $a \in H$.

Comment: Okay, I see. Since I was not interested in any specific case, should I close the question?

Comment: @Anonymous Don't close it. Instead, emphasise that you are interested in the general case. The problem of deciding whether or not an element is contained in a finitely generated subgroup has a name: *The generalised word problem*. This is undecidable in general, but you are asking about additional restrictions which is fine.

Comment: Also, are you assuming that $H$ is non-cyclic? (If $H$ can be cyclic then there is no way to tell whether $ab\in H$, which follows from the undecidability of the word problem for torsion-free groups.)

Comment: Yes, $H$ is non-cyclic